# Manifest from APK vs. Manifest from temp/Stagingarea

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, manifest

Is it normal that Manifest from APK is not he same as Manifest from temp/Stagingarea for a Unity game? And if not what can cause this issue? The APK one is obtained using apktool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is totally normal for APK to not have the same Manifest from temp/Stagingarea. This is because the Stagingarea is use to temporary hold resources before the Android SDK tool is used to build the project. During this time, Unity will generate its Manifest to put it in the temp/Stagingarea area and this Manifest values will be based on the Unity API you used for sensors such as accelerometer, gyro and the vibrator.

Also, Unity will generate more Manifest in sub-folders based on the how many plugins you're using in your project that came with it's own Manifest. Unity will then combine the Manifests into one in the final APK.